# AngularJs application not working in chrome but working in other browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying a simple application but it is not supported in google chrome browser.
I am trying to call html within html page. I am using ng-include directive. This code is working in other browsers like firefox.
Here is my code:
test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="newscript.js"></script>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myModule">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <div ng-include="'Etable.html'"></div>      
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Etable.html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
            <td> {{employee.name}} </td>
            <td> {{employee.gender}} </td>
            <td> {{employee.salary}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

newscript.js

```
var app = angular
        .module("myModule",[])
        .controller("myController", function ($scope) {
            var employees = [
                { name: "Ben", gender:"Male", salary:5000 },
                { name: "Ten", gender:"Female", salary:4000 },
                { name: "Zen", gender:"Male", salary:3000 },
                { name: "Aen", gender:"Female", salary:7000 }
            ];
            $scope.employees = employees;
        });
```

Comment: getting any errors??check html name is same or not

Comment: there're two ng-app ? remove one of them.

Comment: yes,Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Try opening your browser with disabled web security flag: See the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: @Rakeschand removed one but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run your application on a server. If you are using npm then install `npm install http-server` and start the server in your project folder by following command `http-server`.
And start your application on `localhost`.

Comment: I agree, this should allow it to make the proper requests in the app.

Comment: yes, chrome does not support file:/// type so if you are running angular app by just double clicking you head or index.html, then it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

why two ng-app ? you should remove one of theme or you should bootstrap each app manually using `angular.bootstrap ('appname',selector )`

Comment: that was a mistake and even after deleting one, it was not working.